# Creating a random std::vector with ones and zeros C++

Tags: c++, random, stdvector

I want to create a vector of random 1's and 0's in a proportion set by me (in the program I called it dropout) The vector is the same size of a previously created vector CSUM.

in MATLAB it would be

```
dropout=0.9;
n_elements=size(CSUM)
drpoutmask = (rand(n_elements) > dropout);
```

in C++ I have

```
size_t elements = Csum.size();
std::vector<float> y(elements);
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0.0f, 1.0f); 
std::mt19937 engine; // Mersenne twister MT19937
auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
std::generate_n(y.begin(), elements, generator);
std::vector<int> dropoutmask(elements,0);
float dropout=0.9;

for(int i=0; i<elements; i++)
  {
  if(y.at(i)>dropout)
    {
    dropoutmask.at(i)=1;
    }
  }
}
```

which works but for huge vectors is very very slow, is there a faster way to do this? I am very new at C++.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: In MATLAB I meant to say n_elements=length(CSUM) not n_elements=size(CSUM)

Comment: consider `std::bitset` for `dropoutmask` if it's just a flag

Comment: Silly question, are you compiling with optimisations turned on?

Comment: @DiegoFernandoPava you may edit your post by clicking the [edit] link just below the tags list on your post.

Comment: You could also generate the elements of y as you go instead of storing them in a vector. unless you need those later.

Comment: or change the definition of generator to `[distribution, engine, dropout](){return distribution(engine) > dropout;}` and just fill the dropoutmask directly...

Comment: @SteveTownsend is bitset more effective or just less memory-hungry? bit masking takes time.

Comment: afaik `std::bitset` would trade speed for space. As always, measure performance using a profiler.  If heap usage is a hog `std::bitset` might be a better choice.  If nothing else, use `char` not `int` as the mask member.  Using `int` for a 1/0 flag is quite wasteful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You do know about [bernoulli distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution), right? You can use it to generate your integer vector directly.
   Example:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   #include <random>

   int main()
   {
       constexpr double dropout = 0.9; // Chance of 0
       constexpr size_t size = 1000;
       std::random_device rd;
       std::mt19937 gen(rd());
       std::bernoulli_distribution dist(1 - dropout); // bernoulli_distribution takes chance of true n constructor

       std::vector<int> dropoutmask(size);
       std::generate(dropoutmask.begin(), dropoutmask.end(), [&]{ return dist(gen); });
       size_t ones = std::count(dropoutmask.begin(), dropoutmask.end(), 1);
       std::cout << "vector contains " << ones << " 1's, out of " << size << ". " << ones/double(size) << "%\n";
       std::cout << "vector contains " << size - ones << " 0's, out of " << size << ". " << (size - ones)/double(size) << "%\n";
   }
   ```

   Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a160743185ded5c5
2. Alternatively, you can create a integer vector of desired size (This will set all elements to 0), set first N elements to 1, where n is `(1 - dropout) * size` (You said you want a proportion, not random amount close to proportion) and then shuffle vector.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   #include <random>

   int main()
   {
       constexpr double dropout = 0.9; // Chance of 0
       constexpr size_t size = 77;
       std::random_device rd;
       std::mt19937 gen(rd());

       std::vector<int> dropoutmask(size);
       std::fill_n(dropoutmask.begin(), dropoutmask.size() * (1 - dropout), 1);
       std::shuffle(dropoutmask.begin(), dropoutmask.end(), gen);

       size_t ones = std::count(dropoutmask.begin(), dropoutmask.end(), 1);
       std::cout << "vector contains " << ones << " 1's, out of " << size << ". " << ones/double(size) << "%\n";
       std::cout << "vector contains " << size - ones << " 0's, out of " << size << ". " << (size - ones)/double(size) << "%\n";

       for (auto i :dropoutmask) {
           std::cout << i << ' ';   
       }
       std::cout << '\n';
   }
   ```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a9dacd7629e1605

Comment: Good find. But maybe you could provide some code, not a "link-only" answer for the first part.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Done.

Comment: Thank you for referring me to the Bernoulli distribution I did not know that was part of the std. It works great!!